# Sticky navigation on page scroll

Tags: navigation, sticky

I have been trying to implement sticky navigation..something similar to mashable.com
I hv got moderate success in it as my sticky navigation suddenly becomes invisible and then reappears when it reaches to the top.

You can see it live here http://tm.qlogixsolutions.com

And my js looks like this:

```
var $document = $(document),
    $element = $('.column_title_container');

    $document.scroll(function() {
    if ($document.scrollTop() > 330)
    {
        jQuery('.fixed_column_title_container').css({'visibility': 'visible'});
    } else {
        jQuery('.fixed_column_title_container').css({'visibility': 'hidden'});
    }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, I got it fixed by changing css visibility to position